# "show annotation" info in eclipse lost because of formatting, is it possible to restore changeset history after whole file was formatted and commitet?

Tags: eclipse, svn, changeset

His,

I have accidentally applied new formatting to a big xml file and commited it in svn. Because of the new formatting, if I select "Team -> Show Annotation" (Who Modified the Line) all information about previous changesets is lost. Is there a way to revert annotation history?

Reverting my changeset, and commiting it again without applying formatting for the whole file will not work, since the show annotatin view will display my new changeset for every line again.

thanks

edit: additional information

Answer (score 0):

Right-click context menu on the file -> Team -> Show History, then see what version is the proper one.

Comment: sorry, i have described the issue badly. what i need to restore is the "show annotation" information in eclipse for the file. that each line is marked with the changeset that caused the change. right now it is my single changeset that is shown in "show annotation". reverting and commiting should not correct it, since my changeset will be modifying it again. 


i should somehow cancel my last chageset on the server side, i guess?

Comment: Perhaps you could branch the source tree right before the commit, and proceed from there. If that's not acceptable, you may be able to post-facto tag/branch the commit, but I don't know enough about SVN - it might not be possible.

Comment: nope, it didn't work. I tried switching the file to the needed revision and also replacing contents with local history, but after committing the corrections the line annotations show my last revision number for every line :(

Comment: You probably never are getting it back from within Eclipse - have a look at [this page](http://blog.johang.se/2009/03/revert-commit-in-subversion.html), and don't forget to take a backup of your whole repository!